# Running CPPlint on whole project

Tags: google-style-guide, cpplint

I want to run [cpplint.py](https://github.com/google/styleguide/tree/gh-pages/cpplint) on my whole project not for single file to get a report for all C/C++ files in the project. How to do this on macOS and Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just find answer for some part of my question under this great post

["Shell Foo: Getting a cpplint Breakdown Report On All Project Source Files"](http://www.ostricher.com/2014/12/shell-foo-getting-a-cpplint-breakdown-report-on-all-project-source-files/)

Here is the way how to run cpplint for a project on a Mac

```
.python cpplint.py --linelength=120 --counting=detailed $( find . -name \*.h -or -name \*.cc | grep -vE "^\.\/build\/" )
```

For Windows there is a post about integration in Visual Studio.
[How to integrate cpplint.py into Visual Studio](http://sww-it.ru/2015-01-14/1199)

Comment: `$( find . -name \*.h -or -name \*.cc | grep -vE "^./build/" )` escape the `*` s

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ubuntu, so my experience is just reference.

```
./cpplint.py ~/projects/* ~/projects/*/*
# or you can:
./cpplint.py ~/projects/*.* ~/projects/*/*.*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute cpplint on all folder recursively, in Ubuntu you can use:

```
find FOLDER_PATH -iname *.h -iname *.cpp | xargs cpplint
```

where `FOLDER_PATH` is relative or full path to your project folder, also you can specify which files you want to check by name or by extensions and you can concatenate as many you need times,

```
find FOLDER_PATH -iname *.h  -iname *.cpp -iname *.java
```

in my case, i run cpplint inside my project folder and i want to check src folder, so for me it's

```
find ./src -iname *.h  -iname *.cc | xargs cpplint
```

Answer (score 0):

7 year old question. But I just wanted to add that on Windows, you can use PowerShell of course. This is the script that I use, which recurses through every folder from the location where the script is executed, only takes files, and filters on the extensions specified in the array:

```
ForEach(                                                                   `
$item in Get-ChildItem                                                     `
    -Path .                                                                `
    -Recurse                                                               `
    -Include *.cc, *.cpp, *cxx, *.h, *.hpp                                 `
    | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }) {
    python -m cpplint --linelength=80 $item 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [a fork](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint) of cpplink on GitHub, which is available via PyPI:

```bash
pip install cpplint
```

Since [Dec 6, 2015](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/commit/5731a5cd7de05fc88bf7d2be018a01e47052fc3b) it has a `--recursive` argument for `cpplint`

From `cpplint --help`:

> Search for files to lint recursively. Each directory given in the list
> of files to be linted is replaced by all files that descend from that
> directory. Files with extensions not in the valid extensions list are
> excluded.

Below is an example of linting recursively on the `src/` folder:

```bash
cpplint --quiet --counting=detailed --linelength=120 --recursive src/
```

> Default linted extensions are ['c', 'c++', 'cc', 'cpp', 'cu', 'cuh', 'cxx', 'h', 'h++', 'hh', 'hpp', 'hxx'].
> Other file types will be ignored.
> Change the extensions with the `--extensions` flag.