# Running cpplint on all .cpp files

Tags: python, windows, command-line, cpplint

I want to run cpplint.py on all my .cpp files in a folder in Windows CMD.

```
py .\cpplint.py *.cpp
```

This somehow doesn't work. I get the Error:

```
Skipping input '*.cpp': Can't open for reading
Total errors found: 0
```

I thought `*` would be the operator for select all, am I wrong?

P.S.: There's a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308496/running-cpplint-on-whole-project), but it didn't really help.

Comment: Where do you type this command?

Comment: On Windows' CMD.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' CMD doesn't do wildcard expansion: https://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths

It's up to the application to handle the expansion of `*` into paths on Windows, which is in stark contrast to Linux, where the shell itself handles that. So you're passing the string-literal `*` to cpplint.py, which is not a file.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file or from the command line you can do:

```
for %%f in (*.cpp) do py .\cpplint.py %%f
```